# C# NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use a CSV parser which I found on the net in my project.  The problem is I am getting a null reference exception when I try to convert the string to a Tag and my collection does not get populated. Can anyone assist? Thanks

**CSV Parser**

```
private static IEnumerable<string[]> parseCSV(string path)
    {
        List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;
                string[] row;

                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    row = line.Split(',');
                    parsedData.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return parsedData;
    }
```

**Tag Class**

```
  public class Tag
    {
        public Tag(string name, int weight)
        {
            Name = name;
            Weight = weight;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<Tag> CreateTags(IEnumerable<string> words)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> tags = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                int count = 1;
                if (tags.ContainsKey(word))
                {
                    count = tags[word] + 1;
                }

                tags[word] = count;
            }

            return tags.Select(kvp => new Tag(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where was the exception thrown? Look at the stack trace.

Comment: Look at the stacktrace on the exception and it should pinpoint at exactly what line in your code the exception is thrown. You can also debug your code and when it breaks when the exception is thrown you can discover what variable is `null`. If you have an exception handler you need to go into the Debug -> Exceptions dialog and mark the Thrown checkbox for the exception to when the exception is thrown.

Comment: The connection between the 2 code fragments seems to be missing.

Comment: It breaks on this line: foreach (string word in words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Validate all method arguments before you use them!**

> *It breaks on this line: foreach (string word in words)*

Remember that `foreach` loops work by calling `GetEnumerator` on the collection iterated over. That is, your `foreach` loop causes a call to `words.GetEnumerator`, and this call fails if `words` is null.

Therefore, validate your argument `words` by adding a guard at the very start of your `CreateTags` method:

```
if (words == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("words");
}
```

This will help you find the location in your code where `null` is passed into `CreateTags`, and you can then continue fixing the calling code.

**Suggestion: Avoid `null` whenever possible.**

As a very general rule, try to avoid using `null` values whenever possible. For example, when your code is dealing with sets and collections of items, you could make sure that it also works correctly with empty collections. In a second step, make sure that you never use `null` to represent an empty collection; instead, use e.g. LINQ's `Enumerable.Empty<TItem>()` generator to create an empty collection.

One place where you could start doing this is in the `CreateTags` method by ensuring that no matter what the inputs are, that method will always return a valid, non-null (but possibly empty) collection:

```
if (words == null)
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<Tag>();  // You could do without LINQ by writing:
                                     // return new Tag[] { };
}
```

Comment: See "tags[word] = count;" it adds an entry with key 'word' and value 'count' to tags dictionary. Obviously, your simplification is flawed because it will never populate tags.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is that I am trying to store the list of arrays generated from my CSV parser code in the words Iennumerable collection how could I fix this?

Comment: *@Konstantin*, what was I thinking! You're absolutely right. Flawed part of my answer removed, thanks for the correction!

Comment: *@Ben*, before you fix anything, you need to find the *exact* cause. (Adding guard clauses at the methods' beginning that validate arguments will help you there.) I cannot advise you further without more precise information. (The fact that you're storing something in a collection is not *per se* an error. It's OK to pass a `string[]` to `CreateTags`, since `string[]` is `IEnumerable<string>`. However, passing the `IEnumerable<string[]>` from `parseCSV` into `CreateTags` obviously won't work and should result in a type error at compile time. You'd need to call `CreateTags` once per `string[]`.)

Answer (score 0):

Every method should run sanity checks on the arguments it accepts to ensure the arguments are valid input parameters. I would probably do something like

```
public static IEnumerable<Tag> CreateTags(IEnumerable<string> words)
    {
        if(words==null)
        {
           //either throw a new ArgumentException or
           return null; //or return new Dictionary<string,int>();
        }
        Dictionary<string, int> tags = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            int count = 1;
            if (tags.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                count = tags[word] + 1;
            }

            tags[word] = count;
        }

        return tags.Select(kvp => new Tag(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
    }
```

As to why your "words" param is null, it would be helpful to see the CSV file you are trying to parse in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is that I am trying to store the list of arrays generated from my CSV parser code in the words Iennumerable collection how could I fix this?